# Laravel Homestead - page stopped working ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Took my laptop out of house for a couple of days, didn't even get to turn it on during that time. Came back, ready to keep fiddling with my project but the page stopped working all of a sudden. I started getting ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE in the browser.

I've uninstalled homestead box, vagrant, virtualbox, with restart after each, re installed everything, same issue.

I can not ping the `192.168.10.10` address but I can SSH into the box no problem.

Running MacOS Big Sur, VirtualBox 6.1, Vagrant 2.2.18 and whatever the latest homestead version is. Really about quit programming altogether, this is super frustrating. I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you

Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/PHP/test/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

services:
    - enabled:
          - "mysql"
```

Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
customizationScriptPath = confDir + "/user-customizations.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 2.2.4'


Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exist? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "/tmp/bash_aliases"
        config.vm.provision "handle_aliases", type: "shell" do |s|
            s.inline = "awk '{ sub(\"\r$\", \"\"); print }' /tmp/bash_aliases > /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases && chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases"
        end
    end

    if File.exist? homesteadYamlPath then
        settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
    elsif File.exist? homesteadJsonPath then
        settings = JSON::parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
    else
        abort "Homestead settings file not found in #{confDir}"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, settings)

    if File.exist? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "Run after.sh", type: "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if File.exist? customizationScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "Run customize script", type: "shell", path: customizationScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostsupdater')
        config.hostsupdater.remove_on_suspend = false
        config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    elsif Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostmanager')
        config.hostmanager.enabled = true
        config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
        config.hostmanager.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    elsif Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-goodhosts')
        config.goodhosts.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    end

    if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-notify-forwarder')
        config.notify_forwarder.enable = true
    end
end
```

I did try to setup networking [as described here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network) and [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/virtualbox/networking) but nothing worked.
[image]

Comment: You mentioned that you've destroyed the box, but check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#configuring-nginx-sites) again. Try running `vagrant destroy && vagrant up`. As for the changes, did you maybe update your mac? Could it be related to system update? At the end, if Homestead doesn't work for you, don't give up - you could always try to use [laravel valet](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet) or [laravel sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail) (docker approach)

Comment: for what is worth, try another IP - could you have something else on your network with the same IP

Comment: @ljubadr I've done all those and restarted after each, still the same

Comment: @FredericHenri I've done that as well, updated the IP in the Homestead.yaml and in my hosts file to match

Comment: I have the same problem only I am on Ubuntu 20.04 - even after updating homestead vagrant box to the latest (11.5.0) and all packages through composer. So, I suspect an update to Virtualbox/vagrant may have broken something. For what it might be worth, you should still be able to access the project with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: Having the same problem since yesterday, I'm not shure if I updated vagrant & virtualbox through homebrew. having vagrant v. 2.2.18, virtualbox v. 6.1.28 r147628

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the fix, but I couldn't get it running until now:

> Anything in the 192.68.56.0/21 range will work out-of-the-box without any custom configuration per VirtualBox's documentation.

https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1717

Found some more related information here:

https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/vagrant-2-2-18-osx-11-6-cannot-create-private-network/30984/16

---

update 29.10.2021:
I downgraded virtualbox to 6.1.26 and it's working again.

Comment: This was half the solution to my issue, I appreciate it. It did put me on the right path, I've explained below. Thank you!

Comment: After updating to the new release of Fedora I got the same error. Changing the IP as mentioned in this solution got it working back. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going spare over all the broken stuff in VirtualBox >26 ....I need something as convenient as homestead, but not relying on VirtualBox :(

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I really want to say a sincere thank you for all who looked at this and tried to help. I really appreciate it. @ndberg's post above turns out was half the answer. Following his link above, these are the steps I took to "resolve" this issue

ugh

step 1: `192.168.10.10` will not work on VBox 6.1.28, either change it to `192.168.56.**` (i used 4 so its `192.168.56.4`) and update your `/etc/hosts` file to match **OR** do none of that... and just create a `/etc/vbox/networks.conf` file and add `* 192.168.10.0/24` to it. I went with updating existing files, I did not do the latter.

you are still not done

now the issue is Vagrant on the latest Monterey OS

step 2: open the Vagrantfile and add

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   v.gui = true
end
```

In default Vagrantfile that comes with Homestead, I added mine after the first if statement. This will open up the VM window on boot-up and you’d need to minimize/close that window. I am guessing we r  waiting on an update from Vagrant to fix the issue

its working now though

with this comes the somewhat solid conclusion of my VirtualBox journey. Over the years, I've spent countless hours debugging various issues that came with using VirtualBoxes. Its time I try out docker containers instead.

thanks again everyone

Comment: This just solved all problems I ran into! Thank you very much and keep up writing such helpful answers! <3